# PhoneGap 1.4 + Sencha Touch 2 iPhone app submit to app store error

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch, submit, sencha-touch-2

it works fine in iPhone Simulator and iPhone device, with correct code sign, when archive app, submit it to app store in Organizer, it raised the error:

> Your app contains non-public API usage. Please review the errors,
>   correct them, and resubmit your application.
>
> The app reverence non-public symbols in
>   Payload/XXX.app.www/lib/command/vendor/nodejs/osx/node:*NSGetEnviron,*_bzero,
>   fdatasync

is PhoneGap use non-public API?

Comment: hi there, have you fixed it?

Comment: upgrade to PhoneGap 2.7 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look Phonegap related, it looks like it's ST2 related, and more specifically related to the [ST2 command](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/command) as part of the SDK package. You probably don't want to be submitting those files. Use the ST2 command to build a production package, and only import the production files into the Phonegap Xcode project. Read the [command page](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/command) for more information on building your application for production.